# DELETE row FROM table WHERE field value are results of another complex query

Tags: mysql, sql, delete-row

I'm trying deleting rows from a table bananas, where id has to be equal to results of this query:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT (ub.userId) as id
FROM new_users_bonus ub 
JOIN new_users_used_bonus uub ON ub.userBonusId = uub.userBonusId 
JOIN new_bonus_details bd ON bd.bonusId = ub.bonusId
JOIN new_bonus b ON b.bonusId = bd.bonusId
WHERE b.prefix LIKE 'AEJ'
AND (ub.expirationDate <= '2017-10-23'
OR ub.bonusValue - (SELECT SUM(usedValue) as totalUsedValue FROM new_users_used_bonus uub2 where ub.userBonusId = uub2.userBonusId) <= 0)
GROUP BY ub.bonusId, ub.redeemedDate
ORDER BY ub.expirationDate ASC
```

I've written:

```
DELETE FROM bananas WHERE id = ANY (complex query written before)
```

and

```
DELETE FROM bananas WHERE id IN (complex query written before)
```

But, it doesn't erase anything.
Why? What's wrong? I don't receive error message...

Thank you!

Comment: does the `complex query written before` returns any null values?

Comment: Nope, I've tried it and returns 84 rows and all with an id

Comment: If you run `SELECT * FROM bananas WHERE id = ANY (complex query written before)` do you get 0 rows?

Comment: Yes... and I can't understand why

Comment: Then there's no matching id's in the bananas table from the 84 userIDs returned in your other query.

Comment: If I search some of userIDs in bananas' table, I match records...

Comment: Can you provide more details and maybe data?

Comment: What are the data types of `bananas.id` and `new_users_bonus.userId`?

Comment: Mmmh I can say that not all userId are in bananas.id (I've found it now)